# Multiple VPN connections from one Windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn

I want to run a single Windows server that runs multiple instances (IIS sites/app pools) of our API. Each one needs to use VPN to talk to a server within a different customer's network. I have no control over the customer VPN configuration and these may be different providers.

Is there any solution for this, or do I need to use a different server instance for each API / VPN connection?

[image: Very rough server map]

Comment: Any solution for this?? I do have same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge i don't think you can have the same server connected to 3 different VPN's Servers. i think you need to split into 3 vm's to achieve what you need. It's also more secure doing that and don't mixing customers data.